# Web App home icon directs to last page visited

Tags: ios, safari

My web app is a series of linear websites displayed full screen view (no Safari controls or URL window).

When a user exists the app and must return to it by tapping the home screen icon, I need the user to return to the page they left off on. How do I HTML code this into a page(s)?

The home screen icon only directs to one page. Is there something I can do with that page to redirect it to the last page they viewed before taking a phone call (or doing something else)?

Answer (score 0):

You can store the last page they viewed in `NSUserDefaults` in the app delegate's `applicationDidEnterBackground` and restore it when building your initial view.

Comment: Wups sorry I mean in HTML - my app is a web app!

Comment: Is there a way to make a back button in a web app, so when the user exits the app and returns from the home screen icon they can view the last page they were on?